# How to export htmlTable from the viewer to a word document in R

Tags: html, r, html-table, save

I'm working with the `htmlTable` function. While the table renders perfectly in the R studio viewer, I am unable to save, copy and paste, or screenshot it, such that it looks equally nice in the word document I am writing. I was wondering if there was a way for me to export or save the image, such that the table show up just as nice in the word document.

Here is an example table.

```
output <- 
  matrix(paste("Example", LETTERS[1:16]), 
         ncol=4, byrow = TRUE)

library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(output)
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the HTML file and opening the HTML in Word? That approach has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: Thanks for responding. How would I save the output as an HTML file? When I run the code, the output is displayed in the Viewer with no option to save.

Comment: I assume you are using RStudio? You can either add `useViewer = utils::browseURL` as a parameter to htmlTable or click on the "Show in New Window" button in RStudio Viewer pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display your table as grid graphics using `grid.table` function from `gridExtra` library. And save it as image using `ggsave` function from `ggplot` library.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

ggsave(grid.table(output), filename = "~DirectoryName/imageName.png")
```